# vim autoindent stop from removing indents

Tags: vim

I try to use vim with its autoindent feature which works reasonably well. But I find it very annoying that in some situation it removes indents as well because it produces additional work. For example when I have a single indented line, I go to the end of the line and type  then vim removes the indent of the line. How can I turn of the removal of existing indents?

Comment: What kind of code/text are you trying to edit? Could you please give an example?

Comment: I am editing maple *.mpl files whose format I modified in a certain way so that execution groups are defined by paragraphs which are given by lines with at least one indent. I doubt that this will be usefull but it exceeds this format to describe why and how I am doing it exactly. The question should be clear anyway: Can the behaviour to remove indents be turned off?

Comment: I can add that the indenting for maple files depends on http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1116

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried:

```
:set noautoindent   
:set noai  #same as above
```

Or try to do with smart indent

```
:set nosmartindent
:set nosi  #same
```

Comment: I do not want to switch auto-indentation off. It has some good effects. I just want to prevent it from deleting existing indents. That is "too smart" and can be very annoying for the format I am working with.